# Create a vector consisting of connected points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two images (let's name them I1 and I2) of size 512x512 and I want to draw vectors from all pixels in I1 to all pixels in I2. In a way, it would be represented like: 
[I1 pixel 1, I2 pixel 1] 
[I1 pixel 2, I2 pixel 2] 
[I1 pixel 3, I2 pixel 3] 
... and so on 
I was wondering if the following code would create what I am trying to achieve:

```
vector = [I1(1:end); I2(1:end)];
```

EDIT: Since size is showing me x = 2, y = 262144, do I need to transpose it? I'm kinda confused which way the matrix goes...

Comment: check `size(I1(1:end))` to verify the orientation of the vectors you're feeding to your collected output.   But why are you asking at all, since you've already tried it?  If you want to transpose, either add a  " `'`" at the end or flop the way you're merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put something like `vector = [I1(1:end); I2(1:end)]` you will end up with 2-rows metrix. You could try `vector = [I1(:) I2(:)];`, this will give you 2-colums metrix as you wanted.

For example, if you have

`I1 = [1 2 3;4 5 6];` and

`I2 = [10 20 30;40 50 60];`, then

`vector = [I1(:) I2(:)];` will give you `[1 10;4 40;2 20;5 50;3 30;6 60]`

which is size of x=262144 and y=2.